# RSpec should_receive not reaching method in class

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec2, ruby-1.9.3

New to ruby/rspec and trying to test that a method raises an exception.  I may be going about this entirely incorrectly.

```
#require 'rspec'

describe "TestClass" do
  it "should raise exception when my method is called" do
    test = Test.new
    test.should_receive(:my_method).and_raise
  end
end

class Test
  def my_method
    raise
  end
end  


rspec test.rb
F

Failures:

  1) TestClass should raise exception when my method is called
     Failure/Error: test.should_receive(:my_method).and_raise
       (#<Test:0x007fc61c82f7c8>).my_method(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
     # ./test.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00061 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./test.rb:4 # TestClass should raise exception when my method is called
```

Why is the message received zero times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is wrong. In order to test that an exception is raised you'll want to do this:

```
it "should raise exception when my method is called" do
  test = Test.new
  test.should_receive(:my_method)

  expect {
    test.my_method
  }.to raise_error      
end
```

And in this case you likely don't need to add `should_receive`. By calling `my_method` you're making sure that `test` is receiving that method. Basically you're mocking when you don't need to mock.

Comment: Thanks! I'd seen expect referenced elsewhere. I was completely misusing should_receive.

Comment: @sparks yup! :D I struggled for a LONG time with rspec, you'll want to use a cheat sheet for all the various helpers that exist: https://gist.github.com/steveclarke/2353100

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something to call that method. If it is callback [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/725-test-activerecord-callbacks-with-rspec) is examples how to test them.

Comment: That link is probably really confusing to someone that is just starting out with ruby/rspec.